# Get value after a keyword that is in the middle of the line only from given line

Tags: linux, text-processing

Hey so I have the following line in the middle of a file and I only need to get the value following "energy=".
The line number is stored in a variable called "lineNumber".
There are other lines in the file that have the same structure, but with different values. I only want the value of energy from the line defined in "lineNumber".
Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:velocities:R:3:forces:R:3:local_energy:R:1:fix_atoms:S:3 Lattice="42.0000000000       0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   46.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   50.0000000000" temperature=327.11679001 pressure=14.24003276 time_step=5.0000 time=5000.0000 energy=-18.022194 virial="0.46990039            0.48760331     -0.77576961      0.48760331      0.78141847      0.59471844     -0.77576961      0.59471844      0.64787347" stress="-0.00000486          -0.00000505      0.00000803     -0.00000505     -0.00000809     -0.00000616      0.00000803     -0.00000616     -0.00000671" volume=96600.000000 step=1000
```

Comment: You have multiple solutions that'd fail if your data could ever have something like `remote_energy=17` before `energy=-18.022194` in it as they're matching on `energy=` which would match the middle of `remote_energy=`. Please [edit] your question to include that case if it's in any way a possibility in the future.

Comment: Is there always a blank space before your desired `energy=` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a Linux-based system you can almost certainly use GNU `grep`

```
grep -oP 'energy=\K[^\s]+'
```

For example

```
echo 'Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:velocities:R:3:forces:R:3:local_energy:R:1:fix_atoms:S:3 Lattice="…" temperature=327.11679001 … time=5000.0000 energy=-18.022194 virial="0.46990039 …" stress="…" volume=96600.000000 step=1000' |
    grep -oP 'energy=\K[^\s]+'
```

Output

```
-18.022194
```

You can pick out a particular line number using a tool such as `sed`

```
lineNumber=123
sed -n "${lineNumber}{p;q}" file
```

Putting these together,

```
sed -n "${lineNumber}{p;q}" file | grep -oP 'energy=\K[^\s]+'
```

You can use something like `perl` too:

```
perl -e '
    $lineNumber = shift;                                 # Arg 1 is line number
    $fieldName = shift;                                  # Arg 2 is field name
    while (defined($line = <>)) {                        # Read lines from file or stdin
        next unless $. == $lineNumber;                   # Skip until required line
        chomp $line;                                     # Discard newline
        %a =                                             # Create key/value array. Read the next lines upwards
            map { split(/=/, $_, 2) }                    # 3. Split into {key,value} tuples
            grep { /=/ }                                 # 2. Only interested in assignments
            split(/(\w+=(".*?"|[^"].*?)\s+)/, $line);    # 1. Split line into « key=value » and « key="several values" » fields
        print $a{$fieldName}, "\n";                      # Print chosen field value
        exit 0
    }
' "$lineNumber" 'energy' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v lineNumber="$lineNumber" -v FS="energy=" 'NR == lineNumber {print $2}' FILE | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: No need for a pipe and a second call of awk: `awk -v FS="energy=" '{print $2}' FILE | awk '{print $1}'` = `awk -v FS="energy=" '{split($2,a," "); print a[1]}' FILE`

Answer (score 1):

May be overkill for your current need but you could create an array of tag to value mappings (stored in the array `f[]` below):

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^=[:space:]]+=([^[:space:]]+|"[^"]*")' -v n="$lineNumber" '
    NR == n {
        delete f
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[gensub(/=.*/,"",1,$i)] = gensub(/[^=]+=/,"",1,$i)
        }
        print f["energy"]
    }
' file
-18.022194
```

and then you can do anything else you like with any value or combination of values just by indexing `f[]` with the tags (names), e.g. you could write:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^=[:space:]]+=([^[:space:]]+|"[^"]*")' '
    {
        delete f
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[gensub(/=.*/,"",1,$i)] = gensub(/[^=]+=/,"",1,$i)
        }
    }
    (f["time"] < 6) && (f["volume"] > 8) {
        print f["temperature"], f["energy"], f["step"] / f["time_step"]
    }
' file
327.11679001 -18.022194 200
```

or anything else you might need to compare/calculate/print.

The above uses GNU awk for `FPAT` and `gensub()`, you can do the same with any POSIX awk that supports `delete array`, as most if not all do now, with a bit more code:

```
$ awk -v n="$lineNumber" '
    NR == n {
        delete f
        rec = $0
        while ( match(rec,/[^=[:space:]]+=([^[:space:]]+|"[^"]*")/) ) {
            tag = val = substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
            sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
            f[tag] = val
            rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
        print f["energy"]
    }
' file
-18.022194
```

If your awk complains about `delete f` then just change that line to `split("",f)` which will work in any awk.

Answer (score 0):

A sed answer

```bash
sed -En "$lineNumber {s/.*energy=//; s/[[:blank:]].*//; p; q; }" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put ++$ => $/ if ++$ == 1 && m/ \s energy\= <( <+ :N + [\-+.]>+  )> \s /;'   file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put ++$ => $0 if ++$ == 1 && m/ \s energy\=  ( <+ :N + [\-+.]>+  )  \s /;'    file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put ++$ => $<val> if ++$ == 1 && m/ \s energy\=  $<val>=<+ :N + [\-+.]>+   \s /;'   file
```

The Raku code above uses `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags (code is run linewise over the input file). Reading from right-to-left, a match `m/.../` is sought for the desired value following `energy=`. This match is written in the Raku Regex dialect as `<+ :N + [\-+.]>+`  which is a composite character class consisting of any `:N` Unicode number and the characters `-`, `+`, `.`, taken one-or-more times (`-` is one of the few characters that need to be backslash escaped in this construct). This character class can also be written `<+[0..9\-+.]>+`, but you lose matches to Unicode numbers other than `0..9`.

The easiest way to count line numbers in Raku is to run a `++$` auto-incrementing counter starting from one. Putting it all together (now reading left-to-right), the first example code says *"`put` the `++$` line-number followed by the built-in `$/` match variable `if ++$ == 1` if the line-number numerically equals one `&&` the desired match is found, dropping everything outside `<( ... )>` capture markers"*.  Because `&&` is used, the boolean short-circuits. (Remove the `++$ =>` from the output if all you want returned is the value).

Sample Input (OP's data taken three times):

```
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:velocities:R:3:forces:R:3:local_energy:R:1:fix_atoms:S:3 Lattice="42.0000000000       0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   46.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   50.0000000000" temperature=327.11679001 pressure=14.24003276 time_step=5.0000 time=5000.0000 energy=-18.022194 virial="0.46990039            0.48760331     -0.77576961      0.48760331      0.78141847      0.59471844     -0.77576961      0.59471844      0.64787347" stress="-0.00000486          -0.00000505      0.00000803     -0.00000505     -0.00000809     -0.00000616      0.00000803     -0.00000616     -0.00000671" volume=96600.000000 step=1000
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:velocities:R:3:forces:R:3:local_energy:R:1:fix_atoms:S:3 Lattice="42.0000000000       0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   46.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   50.0000000000" temperature=327.11679001 pressure=14.24003276 time_step=5.0000 time=5000.0000 energy=-18.022194 virial="0.46990039            0.48760331     -0.77576961      0.48760331      0.78141847      0.59471844     -0.77576961      0.59471844      0.64787347" stress="-0.00000486          -0.00000505      0.00000803     -0.00000505     -0.00000809     -0.00000616      0.00000803     -0.00000616     -0.00000671" volume=96600.000000 step=1000
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:velocities:R:3:forces:R:3:local_energy:R:1:fix_atoms:S:3 Lattice="42.0000000000       0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   46.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000   50.0000000000" temperature=327.11679001 pressure=14.24003276 time_step=5.0000 time=5000.0000 energy=-18.022194 virial="0.46990039            0.48760331     -0.77576961      0.48760331      0.78141847      0.59471844     -0.77576961      0.59471844      0.64787347" stress="-0.00000486          -0.00000505      0.00000803     -0.00000505     -0.00000809     -0.00000616      0.00000803     -0.00000616     -0.00000671" volume=96600.000000 step=1000
```

Sample Output (tab-delimited return):

```
1   -18.022194
```

---

Finally, if you'd rather input the `lineNumber` off the command-line rather than hard-coding it in the one-liner, `env` environment variables are available inside Raku as the dynamic `%*ENV` hash variable. So you can do the following (note the initial `env` is optional):

```
~$ env lineNumber="1" perl6 -ne 'put $0 if ++$ == %*ENV<lineNumber> && m/ \s energy\=  ( <+[0..9\-+.]>+ )  \s /;'   file
-18.022194
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org